# How to query the views field title in twig?

Tags: drupal-8

I am overriding the [views-view-field.html.twig](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21templates%21views-view-field.html.twig/8.7.x) template file. Inside of the template I need to fetch the right translation of the field_title. Currently the file looks like following

```
{{ output -}}
```

I was trying few options how to fetch the right translation.

```
{{ fields.title.content.langcode }}
```

But it is not working. langcode is passed from preprocess function from the .theme. 
Could you please help me?

I have replaced the {{ output -}} with

```
view.field.title.original_value
```

Now I am trying to fetch the translation of the title. Have tried few options, but none of them is working.

```
view.translation('fr').field.title.original_value
view.field.translation('fr').title.original_value
view.field.title.translation('fr').original_value
view.field.title.original_value.translation('fr')
view.field.title.original_value.langcode
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

to set views field to be translated then you need to do following setting in view.
`Filter criteria -> translation language -> Interface text language selected for page` then all fields get translated based on your page language and you dont need to put extra language code in view template.